# LyapunovSolve does not give me the correct answer

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I am trying to solve an equation using LyapunovSolve, but it does not give me the correct answer. The correct answer should be a 6*6 matrix while by utilizing the Dimension command, it shows me {2}.
The code that I have used is as follows:

```
A = {{-\[Gamma]x, \[Omega]x, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-\[Omega]x, -\[Gamma]x, 0, 
    0, -G, 0}, {0, 0, -\[Gamma]a, \[CapitalDelta]a, g Sin[\[Theta]], 
    g Cos[\[Theta]]}, {0, 
    0, -\[CapitalDelta]a, -\[Gamma]a, -g  Cos[\[Theta]], 
    g Sin[\[Theta]]}, {0, 0, -g Sin[\[Theta]], 
    g  Cos[\[Theta]], -\[Gamma]m, \[CapitalDelta]m}, {-G, 
    0, -g  Cos[\[Theta]], -g Sin[\[Theta]], -\[CapitalDelta]m, -\
\[Gamma]m}};



D0 = {{\[Gamma]x*(2*nb + 1), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, \[Gamma]x*(2*nb + 1),
     0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, \[Gamma]a*(2*na + 1), 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
    0, \[Gamma]a*(2*na + 1), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, \[Gamma]m*(2*nm + 1),
     0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \[Gamma]m*(2*nm + 1)}};


V = LyapunovSolve[A // MatrixForm, -D0 // MatrixForm];


V // Dimensions
```

Does anybody have any idea to fix the problem and find the correct answer?

Comment: `MatrixForm` is a display wrapper and should not be used inside any calculation.

Comment: If you mean that I have to use ```MatrixForm``` when I define A and D0, I should say that It does not fix the problem!

Comment: No, he said you shouldn't use `MatrixForm` at all. Its for printing purposes only.

Comment: I have tried that but it does not work. Actually, without using ```MatrixForm``` running of the LyapunovSolve took along time such that I had no choice except stopping that!

Comment: If after removing `MatrixForm` it does not work, that is a different problem. To understand this, start with something simple such as `m={{1,g},{3,4}};LyapunovSolve[m,{{5,6},{7,8}}]`. You will see that the result is big and `Conjugate[g]` appears. Suppose we know that `g` is real. Then you could use `LyapunovSolve[m,Transpose[m],{{5,6},{7,8}}]` instead, which gives a more compact result. You can try such things in your example. But it is possible that you simply have too many symbols in your matrices, and that the result would be too big, and that the calculation will not finish.